# I have question about group by how to use it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

so, how to split it
as I want to know the group by and by split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to 'chunk' it into groups of 30. To do this, you can use the // operator on the index, which divides by 30 and rounds down to the nearest whole number.

Using 'unstack()' at the end will reshape the dataframe into the format you want.

```
df.groupby([df.index // 30,'sex']).sum().unstack(level=0)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer my question but It works widthways and I want a vertical line and I forgot telling more columns it express time even it shows widthways in result line. i want only "sex" and "value"

Comment: and if there is no group "f" or "m", then what I want values are 0 just within 30 rows calculated and vertical line which have only "f", "m" columns

Comment: Does this deal with your extra columns? `df.groupby([df.index // 30,'sex'])['values'].sum().unstack(level=0)`. You might need to do pandas filtering on the final dataset to only get rows where there is no 'f', or 'm'. Unfortunately I don't have your data so I can only guess what you might be seeing.

Comment: and the vertical line can make as .T